# Converting listed flutter app to PWA app, google login throwing 403

Tags: progressive-web-apps, google-signin, trusted-web-activity

I have a natively flutter build app in the playstore,

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.screener.mobile&pli=1

And I want to convert this into PWA, I used the PWA builder and the app integrity is signed by google

When I generate the package https://www.pwabuilder.com/reportcard?site=https://www.screener.in/ from this website, the apk works fine, even login in with google works, but when I upload the aab file to the app store, the google login in stops working and throws back 403 forbidden error

Can anyone suggest what should be done?